# Can't fix a specific memory leak in Objective-C ARC multithreading iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, memory-leaks

I'm almost breaking my bones to fix a memory leak that instruments is reporting for the following method:

```
- (BOOL)moveCloudFileToLocal: (NSString*)cloudFilePath error: (NSError**)error
{
    // each variable starting with an underscore is an ivar
    BOOL    bSuccess = NO;

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSArray*    paths        = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString*   docPathLocal = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSURL*      sourceURL    = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:cloudFilePath];               // => LEAKING!!!
        NSString*   destFileName = sourceURL.lastPathComponent;
        NSURL*      destFileURL  = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:docPathLocal]
                                            URLByAppendingPathComponent:destFileName];  // => LEAKING!!!
        NSArray*    arrArgs      = @[ sourceURL, destFileURL ];                         // => LEAKING!!!
        NSThread*   thread       = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget: self
                                                           selector: @selector(threadMoveCloudFileToLocal:)
                                                             object: arrArgs];

        _threadCloud = thread;
        [_threadCloud start];
    }

    [self waitForMovingThreadToFinish];

    if (error != nil)
        *error = _retError;

    bSuccess = (_retError == nil);

    return bSuccess;
}
```

Instruments tells me that arrArgs, sourceURL and destFileURL makes a root leak like this:

[image: iELANA/Instruments graphical root leak screen capture]

More informative is this output from Instruments, but I'm not familiar with the result ... so I don't find out which action I have to take that will fix the leak:

[image: iELANA/Instruments structural root leak screen capture]

I've tried additionally to write the following three variables differently like so:

```
NSURL __autoreleasing*      sourceURL...;
NSURL __autoreleasing*      destFileURL...;
NSArray __autoreleasing*    arrArgs...;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't change anything, it keeps leaking the same way. Ok, it's not crashing, but it leaks and I want to repair that. I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 on OS X 10.9.5 using iPhone Simulator with iOS 7.0.3

Any hints available here?

**EDIT as requested, additional code parts:**

```
- (void)threadMoveCloudFileToLocal: (NSArray*)args
{
    //  args:
    //      1:  sourceURL   = iCloud file
    //      2:  destFileURL = local file
    //
    _bgTaskExpired = NO;

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier  bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                                              beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ self->_bgTaskExpired = YES; }];

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

        if ([args count] != 2)
            goto finished;

        {
            NSError*            lastError   = nil;
            NSURL*              sourceURL   = [args objectAtIndex:0];   // sourceURL is the iCloud file
            __block NSURL*      destFileURL = [args objectAtIndex:1];   // destFileURL is the local file
            __block NSError*    theError    = nil;
            __block BOOL        bSuccess    = NO;

            _retError  = nil;
            _fileCoord = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:self];
            [_fileCoord coordinateWritingItemAtURL: sourceURL
                                           options: NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting
                                             error: &lastError
                                        byAccessor: ^(NSURL* newURL)
            {
                NSFileManager*  fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

                if (AfxGetApp().numVersion >= 6.0)
                {
                    bSuccess = [fileManager setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:newURL destinationURL:destFileURL error:&theError];

                    if (bSuccess)
                    {
                        theError = nil;
                        bSuccess = [fileManager evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:newURL error:&theError];

                        if (!bSuccess && [iCloudSupport errorIsFileNotFound:theError])
                        {
                            bSuccess = YES;
                            theError = nil;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // on iPad1 with iOS 5.1.1 it is hanging with the above procedure
                    //...code not being shared, not relevant
                }

                if (bSuccess)
                    [self removeFilePathFromContainers:sourceURL.path];
            }];
            _fileCoord = nil;

            if (lastError == nil && theError != nil)
                lastError = theError;

            if (!bSuccess && lastError == nil)
                lastError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:NSURLErrorUnknown userInfo:nil];

            _retError = lastError;
        }

finished:
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }   // end @autoreleasepool

    [NSThread exit];
}

- (void)waitForMovingThreadToFinish
{
    while (_threadCloud && ![_threadCloud isFinished])
    {
        // Wait for the thread to finish.
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }
}
```

BTW: The static analyzer doesn't find anything in my code, not a single warning. It reveals only when run dynamically. The code is from times when we had iOS 6 and iOS 7 just came out. At that time with the old SDK, I had no complaints. Even **evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:** was not marked for deadlocking in the docs when used with coordinated writing - as it is today in the current docs. It did never deadlock despite running on iOS 5.1.1 - that's why I have the separate conditional **else** part.

**EDIT: additional Instruments output for more clarity**

Before I changed a few lines of code I took this code view from Instruments:

[image: iELANA/Instruments 1st code view of root leak screen capture]

After changing a few lines of code to build up the parameters array that's passed as object within the thread creation statement it looks quite interesting in Instruments, because it's exactly only the NSArray instantiation line that leaks. Unfortunately I don't neither understand why nor do I know how to fix that :-(

[image: iELANA/Instruments 2nd code view of root leak screen capture]

Comment: have you tried with Analyser option? It will show you leaks in detail in your code. It will help to track exact issue.

Check and if it does not help, please post new image where analyser display some warning messages

Comment: First try with suggestion iOS Weblineindia gave you, and if it did not help will you show the code written in threadMoveCloudFileToLocal method ?

Comment: Are you sure your spawned threads are actually exiting?

Comment: How are you managing storage of `_threadCloud`?

Comment: I don't know for sure without testing but I think that by passing auto released variables to another method and on another thread they are probably being released before you're finished with them. Have you thought about doing everything in one method and using dispatch_asynch to determine on which thread you performs certain tasks?

Comment: @iOSWeblineindia: Analyzer keeps totally quiet

Comment: @RASS: What I read from the Instruments output is, that there are too many references kept on the variables; if they were released too early, I'd get  some EXC_BAD_ACCESS violation, which I don't. As I remember from years ago, I also used an attempt with GDC, but at that time, it didn't perform as good as I liked it. So I created my own thread. The thread is actually exiting, _threadCloud is a strong reference of NSThread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the call to `[NSThread exit]`.  It is preventing the root autorelease pool on your thread from draining.

The docs for `+ (void) exit` say:

> Invoking this method should be avoided as it does not give your thread
>   a chance to clean up any resources it allocated during its execution.

Comment: thanks very, very much ... I've learned using the **exit** call years ago and I thought the thread wouldn't exit when the method simply returns. That's not the only place where I used it like so - but the only place that leaked. Now the leak is gone ... and I have to edit out some more invokations.